# File Path for Images

Tags: java, image, file

I know all my code is right except for the path. I have been using `C:/Users/Julian Jacobs/Pictures/Saved Pictures/spaceship/spaceship.png`

I have tried:

1. using `\\` instead of /
2. using _ instead of spaces

Could someone explain the proper formatting and what I need to change in my path?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Content extends JPanel {
int radius = 50;
private Image spaceship;
    public Content() {
        super.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        ImageIcon Ship = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("C:/Users/Julian Jacobs/Pictures/Saved Pictures/spaceship/spaceship.png"));
        spaceship = Ship.getImage();
        Graphics2D g2d= (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(spaceship, 100, 100, this);
        g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY );
        g2d.fillOval(100, 100, radius, radius);

    }
}
```

Throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Content.paintComponent(Content.java:17)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: \\ instead of /

Comment: What is the problem, are you not able to access the file?

Comment: yes, and it must be the address

Comment: Are you using nio? It will give a more specific error message when something goes wrong. iirc the `Users` folder is restricted and can not always be accessed.

Comment: I don't think I am using nio

Comment: Can you show the code you're using the load the file?

Comment: Now that's funny stuff. "I know all my code is right...". Famous last words. The path you have supplied should work just fine unless of course you have spelled something wrong within that path OR the image doesn't exist there OR **your code simply isn't right**. What is the error and show your code.

Comment: For help with "why isn't my code working" you must show the code. Ideally a minimal amount of code as an example of the problem.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: there is more- a lot of unknown source

Comment: So how do you know this is a problem with the path at all?

Comment: I followed a youtube tutorial step by step

Comment: If you're going to supply the full path to your image then just use: ImageIcon Ship = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Julian Jacobs/Pictures/Saved Pictures/spaceship/spaceship.png"); since it's obviously not a resource.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Content.paintComponent(Content.java:17)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)

Comment: at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)

Comment: so DevilsHNd worked

Comment: I had to get rid of the resource code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\\`. That's because `\` is used to specify escape sequences. For example `\n` is newline. `\\` actually gives you a `\`. So, the string `"C:\\Users\\Julian Jacobs\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\spaceship\\spaceship.png"` in Java program gives you: `C:\Users\Julian Jacobs\Pictures\Saved Pictures\spaceship\spaceship.png`. You may verify by using `System.out.println("C:\\Users\\Julian Jacobs\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\spaceship\\spaceship.png")`

Comment: @JulianJacobs You tried that, and it didn't work, but it's still correct because the problem is somewhere other than the path. This correctly answers your question about how to format the path.